# Batch convert HTML file(s) saved using IE to MHT

Tags: conversion, internet-explorer, mht

I have numerous web sites that I've saved over the years.  I used Internet Explorer's "Save As..." option to do this.  It saves the original page as an .html document, and page requirements in a linked folder with the same name as a document.

I want to convert a bunch of these (over 1000) to the single-file .mht format.  This can be done through Internet Explorer or Firefox (using UnMHT extension) by loading the original .html document, then re-saving as an .mht document.  It is tedious to do that for the number of files I'm talking about, obviously.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a utility, command line or otherwise, that can accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like I found what I needed [here](http://www.goldb.org/goldblog/CommentView,guid,19ce47f2-b118-4522-8cc6-ff1b7b10b942.aspx).  Guess I should have googled a little harder first.

Comment: Hi @ultrasawblade, Could you share the the exact link, the above links redirects to your whole gitrepo.

Comment: Dead link! 1 2 3